# Remove unneeded tabs from VS Code in Sidebar

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

On the bottom of the sidebar, you'll see 3 "tabs"; Docker, Commits, & Compare Commits. I can disable them per workspace but next time I open code, it's still there. I've searched everywhere to figure this one out. How do I disable them permanently? All of my search queries returned how to interact with Git and VS Code but not how to disable this feature. I also searched through the Settings in VS Code but didn't find anything related to what I am after.

[image]

Comment: If you search for `showExplorer` in User Settings you'll find the option to hide _some_ of those. I'm also trying to find the Commits and Compare Commits hide settings but so far no luck...

Answer (score 3):

You can right click on any of these, and select "Hide from Side Bar"